# React Codemirror import issue

Tags: reactjs, web, react-hooks, codemirror, google-developers-console

I am facing this error when trying to import codemirror :

> Attempted import error: 'codemirror' does not contain a default export (imported
> as 'codeMirror').
> ERROR in ./src/Component/Editor.js 22:6-29
> export 'default' (imported as 'codeMirror') was not found in 'codemirror' (possib
> le exports: EditorView, basicSetup, minimalSetup)

how can I resolve it ?

I tried npm install codemirror

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to import CodeMirror but the module does not have a default export, you can import it like this instead :

```js
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror';
```

if you are using TypeScript add this line under `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file :

```json
allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true
```